# EMF and Guava Eclipse Java

Tags: guava, emf

I am getting an exception when I try to remove an element from:

```
`org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList<E> using guava Iterables.removeIf...`
```

The exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'no duplicates' constraint is violated
>     at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList.set(AbstractEList.java:262)
>     at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.removeIfFromRandomAccessList(Iterables.java:198)
>     at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.removeIf(Iterables.java:180)
>     at com.mypackage.MyClass$5.applyChanges(MyClass.java:325)

The code which is giving the exception:

```
Iterables.removeIf(EListObj, new Predicate<Variant>()
      {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final Varen varen)
        {
          return varen.getName().equals(varenToDelete.getName());    // varenToDelete declared above in method
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us that you're obviously using a [`UniqueEList`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.2/org/eclipse/emf/common/util/UniqueEList.html) which does indeed not allow duplicate entries. From the context, it's obvious, though.

Because Guava is open-source, you can look at the code and see what's going on in there.

If you look at the implementation of the [`removeIf()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.174) method, or, more concretely, at the [`removeIfFromRandomAccessList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.183) method, you'll see that the algorithm for the removing does indeed introduce short-lived duplicate items in the list. Here's how it works:

1. It iterates the list, maintaining two pointers. One for reading `from` and one for writing `to` the list, named accordingly. The `from` one will get ahead while the `to` will generally not make it to the end of the list.
2. When an item doesn't match your predicate (should not be removed), it is instead copied from the `from` index (it's original position in the list) to the `to` position (the position in the filtered list).
3. Repeat for all items.
4. In the end, cut off the items that were not written to, effectively making the list shorter and only containing teh items we want.

Now, this implementation simply does not work for any kind of `UniqueList`. [I found an existing Guava bug on that issue, #1596.](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1596) Feel free to comment on it / vote for it if it's still possible.

As a workaround, use [`Iterables.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) which doesn't suffer from such limitation. Mind you, it's also lazy, so it works in a different way. If you're not doing anything funky with your list, it should be fine, though.

---

**EDIT 2015/11**:
This was just fixed in Guava 20 (which is not out yet).

Comment: (And please, in the future, always try to look for known bugs/issues with open source libraries such as Guava. That's why they have an open issue tracker.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, as you discussed to look for known bugs, so i have some queries.
 
                      -> I want to know how to look for known bugs/issues, 
                      -> what is open issue tracker. 

Could you help in this regard too ?

Comment: Well, the problem is in Guava, so let's check Guava's page: https://github.com/google/guava. Click Issues: https://github.com/google/guava/issues, search for whatever you're interested in. In this particular case, I tried "removeif" and voilá!

Comment: Do github, contains known issues for every api related to java like guava ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the question. Github contains some Java libraries and the ones that are there usually have a bug tracker there, yes. But lots of libraries are elsewhere, e.g. APache Commons have [their own Jira ](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa). If you have a problem with a framework/library, simply go to the framework/library webpage and see where their bug tracker is.